# Calling onSaveInstanceState on Activity

Tags: android

I inherited a project, trying to understand and solve an old bug.

When I start an activity and let it sit for a bit (sometimes it's almost immediate), but it appears to go into a pause state or something and attempts to reload the activity and gets an error.

"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String ... ' on a null object reference"

I found that when I add this to my activity:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  //super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

It appears to work perfectly.

However, when I uncomment the line above to `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);`, I get the error again.

My activity is extending the ActionBarActivity, if that is helpful.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Related Code:

```
@Override
protected void prepareLayout() {
  textMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
  textNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNotes);

  textMessage.setText(getOneOfMyItems().getText());
  // ... the above line is where the problem error is thrown.
}
```

---

```
Stack Trace:
    Process: com.myproj.myproj, PID: 9272
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myproj.myproj/com.myproj.activities.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.myproj.data.MyItems.getText()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5433)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1810)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7270)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.myproj.data.MyItems.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.myproj.xyz.MyFragment.prepareLayout(MyFragment.java:44)
        at com.myproj.fragments.BaseFragment.prepareAndSetView(BaseFragment.java:49)
        at         at com.myproj.xyz.BaseMyFragment.onCreateView(BaseMyFragment.java:21)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2143)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2089)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1129)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2143)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:615)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3384) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:226) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1810) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7270) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Could you please provide whole error log it's kinda important

Comment: First of all, `ActionBarActivity` has been dead for a really long time, switch over to `AppCompatActivity`. Second, please attach the stack trace of the exception, along with the relevant code snippet.

Comment: My apologies, I added the stacktrace, although, I have changed many of the item names for the purposes of this post.

I have found that ActionBarActivity is old, but I didn't realize it was dead.    I'll be sure to look into changing that.

Comment: My sincere apologies, I am very new to Android dev and it's been a long time since I've posted anything to StackOverflow.  Furthermore, I would like to be very careful what code I post online.

Comment: method `getItem()` does not return a `com.myproj.data.MyItems` but `NULL` ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I had changed the real name of the function to "getItem()" (for this post) which was a very poor choice of names.  It is a function in the parent class, so I renamed it to "getOneOfMyItems()" to better explain it.
It seems that it is returning NULL because the item in question has disappeared from memory or something.  But I am unsure why.  Again, if I leave the "super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);" line commented out, then everything appears to work, but I would imagine that I should be calling the parent's function as well.